# .NET MVC 6 / vNext UserValidator to allow alphanumeric characters

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

What I'm trying to do is simply allow alphanumeric characters in the .NET MVC 6 / vNext registration process and every tutorial I've seen (ie [Configure Microsoft.AspNet.Identity to allow email address as username](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19460078/configure-microsoft-aspnet-identity-to-allow-email-address-as-username)) references `UserManager.UserValidator`, in which is now not available in the current framework.

I've seen this: [UserValidator in Microsoft.AspNet.Identity vnext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30007205/uservalidator-in-microsoft-aspnet-identity-vnext) which looks to be the same issue as mine, but they've taken the `UserNameValidationRegex` property out of the framework since. Brilliant.

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(
                o => {
                    o.Password.RequireDigit = false;
                    o.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
                    o.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
                    o.Password.RequireNonLetterOrDigit = false;
                    o.Password.RequiredLength = 2;
                    //o.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters here seems to be the only logical thing I can access
                })
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

I've found `o.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters`, but with there being no documentation that I've found on this I've no idea what format I have to set that in? Anyone out there that's in the same boat and worked this out?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I took a look at the [aspnet/Identity GitHub repository](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/) and did a search for the property you have found (`AllowedUserNameCharacters`). Here's what I've got.

From the `UserOptions.cs` class in the repo: [[Link Here]](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/src/Core/UserOptions.cs#L17)

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets or sets the list of allowed characters in the username used to validate user names.
/// </summary>
/// <value>
/// The list of allowed characters in the username used to validate user names.
/// </value>
public string AllowedUserNameCharacters { get; set; } = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-._@+";
```

So it would seem that you will need to set this property to be `"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"` (i.e. remove the symbols from the end of the orginally set string. This should achieve what you want.

In terms of why this change was made, according to issue #558, they are trying to move away from regular expressions for increased security. Have a look [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/issues/558) for the full details.

Comment: Really appreciate you spending the time going through the Github repository and answering this one for me, I'm sure it's going to help a lot of others out in the future too. Thank you!

Comment: @ChrisDixon You're welcome sir. Glad it was useful :)

Comment: Just stumbled upon this answer. Seriously?! What about usernames containing e.g. cyrillic characters or umlauts or any other non ASCII UTF8-16 char?! Can this field be empty to skip the check at all?!

Comment: Okay, string.empty skips the check ... meh ... this all seems to be rather overcomplicated atm

Comment: The default value for this has been updated to include the + symbol.
[Issue tracker](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/issues/742) and [source](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/release/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity/UserOptions.cs)

Answer (score 2):

As @DoubleVoid pointed out in the comments, you can use an empty string to allow any characters.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want special character in your email. Try code below

```
    services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options = { 
            options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{|}~.@";
  });
```

Valid email address https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Local-part